# Canvas is not updating even after setting interval

Tags: javascript, html, flask, websocket, socket.io

as the topic states.
I have set the interval to give JavaScript a chance to update my canvas but it just won't. I am not experience with it, but the variables I am "checking" (tried switch but that just breaks) have correct values - they are returned through a flask-socketio websocket on the serverside using a 3rd partylibrary.

The code is shown below, the variables are "global" so they should be in the same scope, I am not sure about the if statements, maybe they just do not work like that in JS? I had trouble using switch for unknown reasons to me (I usually code in C or Python or C++...)

I suspect that my fillstyle just doesn't change, I just don't know why.

Edit: Tried to minimize the code a bit.

Edit 2: The variable "af3_level" that's supposed to have some influence on the fillstyle is changed every 1 second, then send over the socket (it's values are 100% correct).

Edit 3: The problem was "typo" (or maybe not a typo).
It is fillStyle, not fillstyle.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var af3_level;
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        namespace = '/emotiv';
        var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('my_emo_event', {data: 'I\'m connected to emotiv_info'});
        });            
        socket.on('emotiv_response', function(msg) {
            $('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
        });
        socket.on('emo_headgear_data', function(msg) {
          af3_level = msg.af3;
          $('#emotiv_log').html("some text" + af3_level);
          //draw();
        });            
        $('form#emotiv_connect').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('emotiv_connect');
            return false;
        });
        $('form#emotiv_disconnect').submit(function(event) {
            socket.emit('emotiv_disconnect');
            return false;
        });
    });
    var canvas_handle=document.getElementById("connection_quality_canvas");
    var ctx = canvas_handle.getContext("2d");
    setInterval(drawSomething, 1000);
    function drawSomething(){
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas_handle.width,canvas_handle.height);
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.arc(250,250,250,0,2*Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(250,0);
      ctx.lineTo(250,500);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(0,250);
      ctx.lineTo(500,250);
      ctx.stroke();
      //AF3
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(150,55);
      ctx.arc(125,55,25,0,2*Math.PI);
      if(af3_level == 1) {
        ctx.fillstyle = "red";
      }
      else if(af3_level == 2) {
        ctx.fillstyle = "yellow";
      }
      else if(af3_level == 4) {
        ctx.fillstyle = "green";
      }
      else {
        ctx.fillstyle = "black";
      }
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! That is too much code. You need to make a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want help.

Comment: Is this a bit better?

Comment: I made an answer that will hopefully give you an example of how to use switch-statements, and get the code running. For example you have written *fillstyle* instead of the correct *fillStyle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an almost minimal example that hopefully will help you. See comments in code for information.

```js
// Declaring global variables
var
  canvas_handle,
  ctx;
// Declaring global functions
function drawSomething(){
  var
    posX = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas_handle.width),
    posY = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas_handle.height),
    level = Math.floor(Math.random()*3),
    style;

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas_handle.width,canvas_handle.height);
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.lineTo(posX,posY);
  ctx.lineTo(posX + 10 ,posY + 20);
  ctx.closePath();
  
  // This is how a switch-statement looks like:
  switch (level) {
    case 0 : style = '#f00'; break;
    case 1 : style = '#ff0'; break;
    case 2 : style = '#0f0'; break;
    default:
      style = '#000';
  }
  // Notice that the names are lineWith, strokeStyle, fillStyle, and not linewidth, strokestyle or filestyle.
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';
  ctx.fillStyle = style;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Running this code when the document has been loaded and
  // the elements are availible.
  canvas_handle=document.getElementById("connection_quality_canvas");
  ctx = canvas_handle.getContext("2d");
  setInterval(drawSomething, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="connection_quality_canvas" width="500" height="200" />
```

Comment: I see, so the problem is I used "fillstyle" instead of fillStyle... 
Gonna check it out, but that's most probably it.
Yep everything is working now, thanks a lot.. must be the late hour.

Comment: I'm happy it works for you. It easy to make a mistake like that, and I have made similar mistakes several times. I see that you have accepted the answer, and I appreciate that. Did you know that you also can upvote it? :)

Comment: I did, but I do not have the reputation for the vote to be publicly shown.

Comment: Oh, sorry I had forgot about that.

Comment: @nlhnt Looked it up, you need at least 15. I have upvoted your questions, so now you should be able to vote :)

Answer (score -1):

try

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    //your code
}, YOUR_INTERVAL_TIME_IN_MS);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what the poster has problem with. If you look at the code, setInterval is used correctly.

Comment: The problem was fillstyle vs fillStyle.
I am sorry it is 04:34 in here, must be my brain working tricks on me.